# SqlDependency issues, Visual C++ .Net 3.5, SQL Server 2008

Tags: c++, .net, sql, sqldependency

I'm having some issues integrating the SqlDependency service with my Windows Forms App, and I was hoping someone could help a rookie out. I just want to preface this with that, I know my database connection string and my query statements are correct. Additionally, I know that the service broker is enabled on my database. Issuing:

```
SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'Database'
```

Returns a 1 from the query.

I start the dependency in my main forms loading event, like so:

```
SqlDependency::Stop(Get_DB_String());
SqlDependency::Start(Get_DB_String());
```

Then I pull from my database as follows:

```
    bindingSource->DataSource = GetData("Select * From Table", 
                                              Get_DB_String(), 
                                                 dataAdapter);
    dataGridView->DataSource = bindingSource;
```

Where GetData is defined as:

```
DataTable^ GetData( String^ sqlCommand, String^ connectionString, SqlDataAdapter^ adapter )
   {
      SqlConnection^ Connection = gcnew SqlConnection(connectionString);
      SqlCommand^ command = gcnew SqlCommand(sqlCommand,Connection);
      command->Notification = nullptr;              
      SqlDependency^ dependency = gcnew SqlDependency(command);     
      dependency->OnChange += gcnew OnChangeEventHandler(this, &LabSchedule::Form1::OnChange);
      adapter->SelectCommand = command;
      DataTable^ table = gcnew DataTable;
      adapter->Fill(table);  
      return table;
   }
```

And my change handler is defined as follows:

```
System::Void OnChange(System::Object^ sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs^ e)
{

    ISynchronizeInvoke^ i = (ISynchronizeInvoke^)this;

    if (i->InvokeRequired)
    {

        OnChangeEventHandler^ tempDelegate =
            gcnew OnChangeEventHandler(this, &LabSchedule::Form1::OnChange);

        array<System::Object^>^ args = { sender, e };

        i->BeginInvoke(tempDelegate, args);

        return;
    }

    SqlDependency^ dependency = (SqlDependency^)sender;
    dependency->OnChange -= gcnew OnChangeEventHandler(this, &LabSchedule::Form1::OnChange);

    if(dependency->HasChanges)
    {
        // This is where I check the properties of the notification  
        MessageBox::Show(e->Info.ToString() + "\n" + e->Source.ToString() + "\n" + e->Type.ToString());
    }

}
```

When I change something in my database from my local client, it fires the change event and all seems well. However, when I initiate a change from a client on another machine, the OnChange event never gets fired. I'm assuming I'm doing something wacky, but I don't have the insight to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: As an update, I checked the "Type" property of the SqlNotificationEventArgs argument when the event fired locally, and it would return with "Subscription" indicating that the subscription failed. The "Info" property was "Invalid". MSDN says: "The command submitted contained a statement that does not support notifications (for example, an INSERT or UPDATE)." I can't imagine a SELECT statement is invalid; isn't that how you watch the database to begin with?

Comment: Additionally, I tried a tip I came across on another thread to explicitly declare the fields I wanted to retrieve from my table instead of using the wildcard * method. This doesn't appear to have made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seemingly an endless amount of research, the problem I was having was rooted in the design of my table and not my code. Here were the three things that I presumably changed to remedy the problem:

*The statement must not reference the large object types: text, ntext, and image.*

I was using "ntext" as the data type of one of my columns.

*The statement may not use the asterisk (**) or table_name.* *syntax to specify columns.*

Initially, I was using the wildcard to select data from my table.

*The projected columns in the SELECT statement must be explicitly stated, and table names must be qualified with two-part names.*

I wasn't using two-part table names in my SELECT statements, i.e., "Table_name" instead of "dbo.Table_name".

This one was a hard one to peg down, and I hope this helps anyone else having similar issues. I misspoke in my initial description of my problem, because my queries, though perfectly legal, were invalid for SqlNotifications.